# How to pause and resume listening to frames from CvCameraViewListener2

Tags: android, opencv

I want to take in a frame from the camera, do some processing on it and pause the frames coming in until I touch the screen again. Once I've touched the screen, it will resume taking in frames and process the next one. What I've done is disable the view inside onCameraFrame and re-enable it inside the onTouch:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    final Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    final Mat gray = inputFrame.gray();

    if (mEstimator.getProcessFrameDone()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Process frame done.");
        mResumeFrameCapture = true;
        mProcessThisFrame = false;
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();

    }

    if (mProcessThisFrame) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Processing frame.");
        mEstimator.processFrame(rgba);

    }

    Core.flip(rgba, rgba, 1);
    return rgba;
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Screen touched.");

    mProcessThisFrame = true;

    if (mResumeFrameCapture) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Resuming frame captures.");
        mEstimator.setProcessFrameDone();
        mProcessThisFrame = false;

        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6,
        mContext, mLoaderCallback);
    }
    mResumeFrameCapture = false;
    return false;
}
```

The problem is, I don't think disableView is working properly. When I run it through the debugger, I can't even step over it. It just hangs. However, when you press the multi-task button and make it pause on purpose, onPause runs the same disableView code and you can step over it fine. I've tried running onPause directly, but it still doesn't work. Any ideas on how to disable the view properly?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out why. It's because you can't disable the view inside the OnCameraFrame function. You have to do it outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just type the following when you want pause:

```
cameraBridgeViewBase.setVisibility(SurfaceView.INVISIBLE);
```

And the following when you want to resume:

```
cameraBridgeViewBase.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
```

Disclaimer! This dosen't actually pause the stream and just removes the visibility so one can display any other object on the screen.